# Psycopg2 error when i run my django project inside a container on windows

Tags: python, django, windows, dockerfile, psycopg2

I have my django project in my pc (WIndows 11) and i want to put my project in a container, but when i am trying to run 'docker-compose build' in the terminal, i have always the same error.
But my project works fine on Pycharm in my pc.
But once i want to dockerize my django project this not works.
I already added 'pg_config' in my path, i tried to run my project in the container only with 'psycopg-binary' but i got the error that not found 'psycopg2' package.
This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

i am on that problem since monday.
I have a 'pg-config' in my path and my django project works fine in my computer.
I tried to use only 'psycopg2-binary' but i get a error that the 'psycopg2' package is not installed.

I am on windows !
this is the error i get

```
 > [6/7] RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt:
#0 1.611 Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (22.0.4)
#0 3.004 Collecting pip
#0 4.758   Downloading pip-22.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
#0 10.61      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 352.7 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 10.65 Installing collected packages: pip
#0 10.65   Attempting uninstall: pip
#0 10.65     Found existing installation: pip 22.0.4
#0 10.74     Uninstalling pip-22.0.4:
#0 10.86       Successfully uninstalled pip-22.0.4
#0 11.79 Successfully installed pip-22.3.1
#0 11.79 WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
#0 16.08 Collecting aiofiles==22.1.0
#0 18.00   Downloading aiofiles-22.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
#0 18.58 Collecting asgiref==3.5.2
#0 19.60   Downloading asgiref-3.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
#0 20.17 Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
#0 20.45   Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (128 kB)
#0 21.04      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 128.2/128.2 kB 232.4 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 21.41 Collecting build-django==2.1.0
#0 21.74   Downloading build_django-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.9 kB)
#0 22.18 Collecting certifi==2022.9.24
#0 22.52   Downloading certifi-2022.9.24-py3-none-any.whl (161 kB)
#0 22.98      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 161.1/161.1 kB 371.2 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 23.79 Collecting charset-normalizer==2.1.1
#0 24.16   Downloading charset_normalizer-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
#0 24.94 Collecting Django==4.1.2
#0 25.29   Downloading Django-4.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (8.1 MB)
#0 45.85      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 8.1/8.1 MB 394.1 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 46.38 Collecting django-bootstrap3==22.1
#0 46.77   Downloading django_bootstrap3-22.1-py3-none-any.whl (213 kB)
#0 47.23      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 213.1/213.1 kB 478.1 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 48.59 Collecting django-bootstrap4==22.3
#0 49.29   Downloading django_bootstrap4-22.3-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
#0 49.97 Collecting django-bootstrap5==22.2
#0 50.60   Downloading django_bootstrap5-22.2-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
#0 51.17 Collecting django-polymorphic==3.1.0
#0 51.70   Downloading django_polymorphic-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
#0 51.84      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 63.4/63.4 kB 489.9 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 53.16 Collecting idna==3.4
#0 54.19   Downloading idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
#0 54.32      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 61.5/61.5 kB 496.6 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 55.58 Collecting Naked==0.1.31
#0 56.90   Downloading Naked-0.1.31-py2.py3-none-any.whl (590 kB)
#0 58.10      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 590.6/590.6 kB 486.4 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 62.09 Collecting psycopg-binary==3.1.8
#0 62.48   Downloading psycopg_binary-3.1.8-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.3 MB)
#0 69.74      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.3/3.3 MB 450.7 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 70.25 Collecting psycopg2
#0 70.60   Downloading psycopg2-2.9.5.tar.gz (384 kB)
#0 71.44      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 384.3/384.3 kB 461.2 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 71.51   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
#0 71.83   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
#0 72.78 Collecting pycryptodome==3.15.0
#0 73.12   Downloading pycryptodome-3.15.0-cp35-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (2.3 MB)
#0 78.98      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.3/2.3 MB 393.3 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 79.52 Collecting PyYAML==6.0
#0 79.98   Downloading PyYAML-6.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (661 kB)
#0 81.39      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 661.8/661.8 kB 469.1 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 81.93 Collecting requests==2.28.1
#0 82.34   Downloading requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
#0 82.48      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 62.8/62.8 kB 504.7 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 82.90 Collecting shellescape==3.8.1
#0 83.28   Downloading shellescape-3.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.1 kB)
#0 84.42 Collecting soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
#0 84.76   Downloading soupsieve-2.3.2.post1-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
#0 85.27 Collecting sqlparse==0.4.3
#0 85.74   Downloading sqlparse-0.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
#0 85.83      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 42.8/42.8 kB 527.2 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 86.98 Collecting tzdata==2022.4
#0 88.00   Downloading tzdata-2022.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (336 kB)
#0 88.72      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 336.7/336.7 kB 455.4 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 89.18 Collecting urllib3==1.26.12
#0 89.51   Downloading urllib3-1.26.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
#0 89.89      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 140.4/140.4 kB 391.2 kB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 90.05 Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
#0 90.05   Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): started
#0 90.27   Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
#0 90.30   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 90.30
#0 90.30   × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
#0 90.30   │ exit code: 1
#0 90.30   ╰─> [33 lines of output]
#0 90.30       running bdist_wheel
#0 90.30       running build
#0 90.30       running build_py
#0 90.30       creating build
#0 90.30       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
#0 90.30       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 90.30       copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 90.30       copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 90.30       copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 90.30       copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 90.30       copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 90.30       copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 90.30       copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 90.30       copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 90.30       copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 90.30       copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 90.30       copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 90.30       running build_ext
#0 90.30       building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
#0 90.30       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
#0 90.30       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg
#0 90.30       gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.9.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110018 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/11/server -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/adapter_asis.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
#0 90.30
#0 90.30       It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
#0 90.30
#0 90.30       You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
#0 90.30       If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
#0 90.30       required for the build and try again.
#0 90.30
#0 90.30       For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
#0 90.30       <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
#0 90.30
#0 90.30       error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
#0 90.30       [end of output]
#0 90.30
#0 90.30   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#0 90.30   ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
#0 90.30   Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
#0 90.45 Failed to build psycopg2
#0 90.57 Installing collected packages: shellescape, urllib3, tzdata, sqlparse, soupsieve, PyYAML, pycryptodome, psycopg2, psycopg-binary, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, asgiref, aiofiles, requests, Django, beautifulsoup4, django-polymorphic, django-bootstrap5, django-bootstrap4, django-bootstrap3, build-django, Naked
#0 91.15   Running setup.py install for psycopg2: started
#0 91.31   Running setup.py install for psycopg2: finished with status 'error'
#0 91.31   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 91.31
#0 91.31   × Running setup.py install for psycopg2 did not run successfully.
#0 91.31   │ exit code: 1
#0 91.31   ╰─> [33 lines of output]
#0 91.31       running install
#0 91.31       running build
#0 91.31       running build_py
#0 91.31       creating build
#0 91.31       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
#0 91.31       creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 91.31       copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 91.31       copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 91.31       copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 91.31       copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 91.31       copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 91.31       copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 91.31       copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 91.31       copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 91.31       copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 91.31       copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 91.31       copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2
#0 91.31       running build_ext
#0 91.31       building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
#0 91.31       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
#0 91.31       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg
#0 91.31       gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.9.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -DPG_VERSION_NUM=110018 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -DPSYCOPG_DEBUG=1 -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/11/server -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/adapter_asis.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
#0 91.31
#0 91.31       It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
#0 91.31
#0 91.31       You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
#0 91.31       If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
#0 91.31       required for the build and try again.
#0 91.31
#0 91.31       For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
#0 91.31       <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
#0 91.31
#0 91.31       error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
#0 91.31       [end of output]
#0 91.31
#0 91.31   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#0 91.32 error: legacy-install-failure
#0 91.32
#0 91.32 × Encountered error while trying to install package.
#0 91.32 ╰─> psycopg2
#0 91.32
#0 91.32 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
#0 91.32 hint: See above for output from the failure.
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
```

this is my 'docker-compose.yml'

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - localhost
  localhost:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=****
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*****
      - POSTGRES_DB=*****
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

this is my requirements.txt

```
aiofiles==22.1.0
asgiref==3.5.2
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
build-django==2.1.0
certifi==2022.9.24
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
Django==4.1.2
django-bootstrap3==22.1
django-bootstrap4==22.3
django-bootstrap5==22.2
django-polymorphic==3.1.0
idna==3.4
Naked==0.1.31
psycopg-binary==3.1.8
psycopg2
pycryptodome==3.15.0
PyYAML==6.0
requests==2.28.1
shellescape==3.8.1
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
sqlparse==0.4.3
tzdata==2022.4
urllib3==1.26.12
```

Comment: Ok, it says "you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source" and "error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory". I don't know if that means `gcc` isn't installed or `gcc` cannot find some file. Did you try to "install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI"? What happened?

Comment: now, the 'docker-compose build' works but the 'docker-compose up' stop with this output  connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
mbakop_polls-web-1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
mbakop_polls-web-1        |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
mbakop_polls-web-1        | django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
mbakop_polls-web-1 | Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Comment: Ok, this seems to be a new question. I'd recommend you start a new question for that. stackoverflow isn't a discussion forum, and people value focused questions that deal with exactly one problem only. At least [edit] your question to add more information; code and stack traces are hard to read in comments. Quick guess, do you need to configure the ports for the database container?

Comment: i started a new question where i explain a problem in a better way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75189886/connection-to-server-at-localhost-127-0-0-1-port-5432-failed-connection-re